# Meaning of adopt from

Tags: usage

> The recommended prevention strategy — making sure that no child goes to bed without eating a meal — **adopted from** 2015 ensured a sharp drop in the number of children falling sick.
>
> https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/editorial/the-litchi-link/article28022573.ece

Why have they used **adopted from** to me it doesn't sound idiomatic and I think in its place **adopted in** should be used because the event happened **in 2015** not **from 2015**.

Am I correct?

Comment: To my mostly-British ears **adopted in 2015** sounds better too.  **Adopted from 2015 to 2016** makes sense with **from** is indicating the start of a period.

Comment: **Adopted from 2015**  could also mean there was a previous similar strategy in 2015 and they are using all or part of it in a later plan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that the more idiomatic use is "adopted in"

> the strategy was **adopted in** 2015.

However, as jonathanjo points out, the writer may have used "adopted from" to imply that the strategy has been continually active *since* the date it was adopted.

Although I would not use it myself, I don't have a problem with it.  It's not particularly elegant, as an "adoption" is a singular event in time, not an ongoing process, but nevertheless it makes sense as shorthand.

Still, if it doesn't sound right to you, don't use it.  There are more idiomatic ways to say the same thing.

> the strategy **has been active since its adoption in** 2015